# php auto-page creation

Tags: php, mysql

i already have asked this question but now i'll be more specific.I have a videoupload page and need a php script for creating a page for every video.

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$source=$_FILES['filename'];
```

Then i do all the MySQL connection and insert the data into my database

```
$result=("INSERT INTO videos(Name,Source)VALUES($name,$source)");
```

But the problem is i also need a script that would create a page for every video on the basis of video.html

```
<html>
<video>
<source src="<?php .$source;?>">
<?php
```

`$source=("SELECT FROM videos WHERE name="$name"");
?>`

Comment: Still not quite clear enough. Where is it failing? There are a lot of syntax errors in your example. Obligatory security warning for inserting a value into the db without sanitization.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want to do is just use the **.htaccess** file and **mod_rewrite**

You can then connect the url:

```
www.example.com/video/12345/the-funny-dog
```

to actually call

```
www.example.com/video.php?videoID=12345
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want to create a page for *every video*, even you're working with a database?

**That's the wrong way!**

The right way would be **one file**:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['ID']) {

    $ID = intval($_GET['ID']);

    $sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM videos
        WHERE ID = '.$ID;
    // do further sql stuff and display video
}
else {
    echo 'No video found with this id';
}
?>
```

If you name this file video.php you can just reach every video with:

**video.php?ID=1**

etc.